# Automate a Excel VBA Function

Tags: vba, excel

I Need a help in Excel VBA. I want to develop a function that will automatically apply the function to selected range of Cells. My Sample Code is Here it work Independently for a single row I want to apply it for minimum 500 rows.

```
Sub Value() ' ' Value For the Insurance Rate

    Dim percentage As Double
    Dim year As Double

    percentage = Sheet5.Range("R2").Value
    year = Sheet5.Range("Q2").Value

    If percentage <= 85 And year <= 25 Then
        Sheet5.Range("S2").Value = Sheet4.Range("D13").Value

    ElseIf percentage <= 85 And year > 25 Then
        Sheet5.Range("S2").Value = Sheet4.Range("C13").Value

    ElseIf percentage > 85 And percentage <= 90 And year <= 25 Then
        Sheet5.Range("S2").Value = Sheet4.Range("D8").Value

    ElseIf percentage > 85 And percentage <= 90 And year > 25 Then
        Sheet5.Range("S2").Value = Sheet4.Range("C8").Value

    ElseIf percentage > 90 And percentage <= 95 And year <= 25 Then
        Sheet5.Range("S2").Value = Sheet4.Range("D5").Value

    ElseIf percentage > 90 And percentage <= 95 And year > 25 Then
        Sheet5.Range("S2").Value = Sheet4.Range("C5").Value

    ElseIf percentage > 95 And year <= 25 Then
        Sheet5.Range("S2").Value = Sheet4.Range("D3").Value

    ElseIf percentage > 95 And year > 25 Then
        Sheet5.Range("S2").Value = Sheet4.Range("C3").Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your attempt so far? Stack Overflow is not a code writing/modification service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close. I just converted your procedure into a User Defined Function, which can then be used like built-in Excel functions in the Excel Window.

Here's the code:

```
Function myValue(percentage As Double, year As Double) ''Value For the Insurance Rate

    If percentage <= 85 And year <= 25 Then
        myValue = Sheet4.Range("D13").Value

    ElseIf percentage <= 85 And year > 25 Then
        myValue = Sheet4.Range("C13").Value

    ElseIf percentage > 85 And percentage <= 90 And year <= 25 Then
        myValue = Sheet4.Range("D8").Value

    ElseIf percentage > 85 And percentage <= 90 And year > 25 Then
        myValue = Sheet4.Range("C8").Value

    ElseIf percentage > 90 And percentage <= 95 And year <= 25 Then
        myValue = Sheet4.Range("D5").Value

    ElseIf percentage > 90 And percentage <= 95 And year > 25 Then
        myValue = Sheet4.Range("C5").Value

    ElseIf percentage > 95 And year <= 25 Then
        myValue = Sheet4.Range("D3").Value

    ElseIf percentage > 95 And year > 25 Then
        myValue = Sheet4.Range("C3").Value
    End If
End Function
```

Then in cell `S2` (or any other cell you want to use the function) you would enter

`=myValue(R2,Q2)`

Also note, that I change the name of the function to `myValue` to not run into issues with the built in `Value` members in VBA.

Comment: Thanks a lot friend, My very big burden is solved now. thanks a lot it worked....

Comment: but it is bit hetic, because i have to manually change the cell reference, it is possible to drag the formula to the desired row

Comment: Which cell references are you having to manually change? `R2` and `O2` or the ones in the code?

Comment: R2 and Q2 will keep changing like
S2 => R2 Q2
S3 => R3 Q3 as so on

Comment: I've updated, the answer. It's just a matter of removing each $ in the formula.